# EM_JS : unable to free const char* in cpp

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

```
    EM_JS(const char*, get_todo_item, (const char *str), {
        return Asyncify.handleAsync(async() => {
            const text = UTF8ToString(str);
            out("text >> " + text);
            let response = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
            response = await response.json();
            var lengthBytes = lengthBytesUTF8(jstring)+1;
            var stringOnWasmHeap = _malloc(lengthBytes);
            stringToUTF8(jstring, stringOnWasmHeap, lengthBytes);
            return stringOnWasmHeap;
        });
    });

int main()
    {       
        const char*  response = get_todo_item("4455454545");
        std::free( response);
        return 0;
    }
```

Got compilation error : `cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void *' with an lvalue of type 'const char *' std::free( response);`
Also tried: `std::free((char *)response)` successful compilation but memory is not freed when checking with cout.
Followed documentaion from : https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html#c.EM_JS

Comment: `but memory is not freed when checking with cout.` Why do you think so?

Comment: @eerorika I checked "cout" basically it is printing assinged value after running free() also. I dont know why thats happening :(

Comment: If you attempt to print a value in deallocated memory, then behaviour of your program is undefined. You cannot make a conclusion of "not freed" based on undefined behaviour.

Comment: It doesn't behave undefined. It just prints out the value assigned which means its memory is not free. right?

Comment: When the behaviour of the program is undefined, then it can have any behaviour. Printing out a value is included in the list of all possible behaviours. Therefore a program which has undefined behaviour may print a value.

Comment: @eerorika How can i check if the memory is freed or not ?

Comment: There is no way to check within the language. There are tools however. I've used valgrind.